# How can I center align my image into div?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div meant to contain all content on said site, an image I have nested into the div doesn't want to center and I'm not sure why?

here is the CSS.

```
#wrapper {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #f4f9f1;
}

#intro {
padding-bottom: 10px;
width:80%;
margin:10px auto;
border-bottom: 3px solid #b32230;
}
```

intro is the id given to said img, it just floats to the left of the div( id is wrapper) and wont center even though I have right and left margins set to auto?

Comment: add text-align:center to wrapper

Comment: If you want any additional information, you should check out this CSS-Tricks article for all things centering.  http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `margin: auto;` is that it will only center block level elements ... and `img` is by default displayed as `inline` and follows the text flow (to the left). If you add **`display: block`** to it it should work:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/0830c23s/)**

```
#intro {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width:80%;
    margin:10px auto;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b32230;
}
```

This way you don't need to centrally align the text of the wrapper element.

But if you want to center all `inline` children of the the wrapper - just use **`text-align:center`** on the `#wrapper` ... however then you may need to have line breaks before and after the images or some text could end up next to them and push them out of the center =)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/9oy739qr/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: center` on main container:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f4f9f1;
    text-align: center;/*Add text-align center*/
}
```

Comment: or display the image as a block, depending on OP's needs